# Jersey Rest API call which sends file is not handled correctly by Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jersey, tomcat8

Hopefully simple question.

I have a Jersey Rest API call which returns a file using StreamingOutput like this:

`Response.ok(stream).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"").build();`

The endpoint is: /rest/export
Method: POST
Host: http://www.example.com

I can test it LOCALLY (http://localhost/rest/export) using a Rest Client running under Jetty and it works fine.  When it is deployed in Tomcat the same call fails.  I believe some configuration in Tomcat is causing issues.  I am getting:

> 504 Gateway timeout

My question is what config settings do I have to use in order for it to allow this rest api to go through? I tried a whole bunch but nothing seems to work correctly.

My Tomcat installation is default no changes have been made to any configuration.

Thank you for any information/help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was actually due to some incompatibility with StreamingOutput and DeclarativeLinking.  Turning off linking resolved the issue.  However switching to InputStream as the Response also will resolve the issue.